# What would be the Big O notation for this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Determine whether the string contains at least 1 repeatable character.

(Implying that string can contain only basic ASCII alphabet: 128 characters).

```
bool hasRepeatableChar(String str) { 
    if (str.length() > 128) {
            return true;
    }
    str = str.sort();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) {
        if (str[i] == str[i+1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

As I can see, it is:

- **O(n log n)** for str.length() <= 128, *where n - length of a string*
- **O(1)** for str.length() > 128

But what will be an amortized big O value?

---

P.S.

Instead of sorting it can also be done by using some kind of data structure (map, for example), it will reduce the amount of operations to O(n) but increase memory cost. Anyway, it isn't related to the question.

Comment: It's O(n log n)

Comment: @MauricePerry But why? It will definitely be O(n log n) for some range (0 < str.length < 129) but it also will be O(1) for a much larger number of cases (129 < str.length < ∞).

Comment: By 128 characters, they probably mean what characters are allowed in the string, not the length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the time complexity of this algorithm is `O(1)`, because the number of operations `T(n)` does not depend on the size of the input (for large enough `n`) and is bounded by some constant number of operations.

Answer (score 3):

An [amortized analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) of an algorithm should be based on the expected inputs.

In your case - without any prior knowledge about the distribution of the length of expected inputs - there is no much you can say.

In other words - the term "amortized complexity" without assumptions about the inputs doesn't have much meaning for your algorithm.